# wdReplaceAll empty replacement text doesn't work

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have taken over a macro on a word document which has the following function:

```
Private Sub ConvertTildeToBullets()
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "~ "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Replacement.style = ActiveDocument.Styles("ieMR table bullet 1")
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

So it converts a sentence starting with a tilde (~) to bullet style. The program that outputs the original word document puts a space after the tilde and at the bottom of the function it replaces the tilde and space with a space. However my boses don't want that space and as soon as it is changed to `.Replacement.Text = ""` it doesn't replace any of the tildes.

How to I run wdReplaceAll with an empty replacement text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with changing three lines of your code:

```
....
.Text = "(~ )(*)"
....
.MatchWildcards = True
....
.Replacement.Text = "\2"
....
```

It works for quick test & try I just made. Hope it will work for you as well.

Comment: when you use round brackets in search text you separate what you search into section. Next, in replacement section you could refer to these sections with this syntax: `\section`. In our situation we search for section 1=`~ ` and section 2=`*` which is anything. Next, we ask to return only section 2 by setting replacement text = `\2`. Quite useful site explaining this and other replacement techniques you will find [HERE](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm).